# Apex batch is failing to Delete the records, giving an error

Tags: batch, errormessages

We have scheduled a batch apex for deleteing 400K records daily intially it was worked fine but from last few days that batch job is terminating by giving this error

First error:

> SQLException [common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-01013: user
>   requested cancel of current operation select
>   /*ApexBatch.Class.PlanDeleteBatch.start: line 33*/ * from (select *
>   from (select t.custom_entity_data_id "Id" from (select /*+ ...

I have raised a ticket with salesforce.com also but no luck. Can any one help on this?

Here is my code:

Batch Class:

```
global class PlanDeleteBatch implements Database.batchable<SObject>{

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.batchableContext info){
       String query;
       if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
           query = ('SELECT Id FROM data__c');
       } else {
           query = ('SELECT Id FROM data__c' );
       }
       return Database.getQueryLocator(query); /* <-- error throwing here in error message */
   }   

   global void execute(Database.batchableContext info, List<data__c> scope) {
       delete scope;
   }   

   global void finish(Database.batchableContext info){   }
}
```

This is clearing the recycle bin operation.

After clearing the recycle bin also it is giving the same error again.

Comment: What's the chunk size set to when you are calling Database.executeBatch?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bad error message - according to this knowledge article:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000175555&language=en_US

the underlying problem is that your query was aborted because it took longer than 2 minutes to complete.

There's some good advice (and links) regarding query optimisation at:

http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/07/maximizing-the-performance-of-force-com-soql-reports-and-list-views.html